# How to connect Oracle DB from WSL2 using cx_Oracle?

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I am using WSL2 Ubuntu for my Python applicaton. The error I am getting is "ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist". `cx_Oracle.connect()` output in debug mode below.

```
ODPI [02506] 2022-02-04 09:59:17.775: ODPI-C 4.3.0
ODPI [02506] 2022-02-04 09:59:17.775: debugging messages initialized at level 64
ODPI [02506] 2022-02-04 09:59:17.779: Context Parameters:
ODPI [02506] 2022-02-04 09:59:17.779:     Oracle Client Lib Dir: /opt/oracle/instantclient_21_5/
ODPI [02506] 2022-02-04 09:59:17.779: Environment Variables:
ODPI [02506] 2022-02-04 09:59:17.779:     ORACLE_HOME => "/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_5"
ODPI [02506] 2022-02-04 09:59:17.779:     TNS_ADMIN => "/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_5/network/admin"
ODPI [02506] 2022-02-04 09:59:17.779:     LD_LIBRARY_PATH => "/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_5:"
ODPI [02506] 2022-02-04 09:59:17.779: load in parameter directory
ODPI [02506] 2022-02-04 09:59:17.779: load in dir /opt/oracle/instantclient_21_5/
ODPI [02506] 2022-02-04 09:59:17.779: load with name /opt/oracle/instantclient_21_5//libclntsh.so
ODPI [02506] 2022-02-04 09:59:17.784: load by OS successful
ODPI [02506] 2022-02-04 09:59:17.784: validating loaded library
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=X)(PORT=X))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=X)))
ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
```

Python code:

```
import cx_Oracle

cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir="/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_5")

dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn("X","X",service_name="X")

print(dsn)

try:
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user="X", password="X",
                               dsn=dsn,
                               )
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Same code works on my local windows machine. Is there any additional config for WSL ?

Comment: What do you use as a host? AFAIK WSL2 distro is registered under IP other than localhost. Try to check if you can reach oracle port from host (windows).

Comment: Update your post with the problem.  Are you getting a loading error?  The error you show could be expected from the sample connection string you show - I presume you are actually using valid values in your app?  Some comments: with Instant Client, don't set ORACLE_HOME.  Also there is no need to set TNS_ADMIN to the default location.  You may as well unset this variable.

Comment: Because you're on Linux, the call to initOracleClient doesn't do what you think it does. It does force the client libraries to be loaded when it is called but the system library search path (via ldconfig or LD_LIBRARY_PATH) must still be set before the process starts. In fact, if you pass a different client path to the one set in the environment you could end up with a clash. The initOracleClient(libDir) usage is really only helpful on Windows and macOS. Note that on all platforms, if you don't call initOracleClient, then the libs are loaded when the first connection is opened

Comment: @ChristopherJones I'm getting "ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist". Yes I am using valid values for host, port and service name parameters.

Comment: @Roman I use Windows 10 as the host. Already tested ping and telnet from WSL2 to the oracle database, both are ok.